# Isotope filter doesnt works on child added later to the main item selector

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using isotope provided by [metafizzy](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) on a div with different filters and it works very well for me like this. But when I later add a child `div` to this `div` having id `communitymembers`, the isotope filter doesnt work for that child.

```
         $container = $('#communitymembers').isotope({
              itemSelector: '.item-select',
              filter: function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var searchResult = commMemberKeywordSearchFilter ? $this.find('.memberName').text().match( commMemberKeywordSearchFilter ) : true;
                    var expertiseResult = $this.is(commMemberExpertiseFilter);
                    var distanceResult = commMemberDistanceFilter ? $this.find('.communityLocation').attr("data-com-loc") < parseInt(commMemberDistanceFilter) : true;
                    return searchResult && distanceResult && (expertiseResult || commMemberExpertiseFilter=='');
                }
            });
               $('.filtercheck').change( function() {
                var inclusives = [];

                $('.filtercheck').each( function( i, elem ) {   
                    if ( elem.checked ) {
                        inclusives.push(elem.value);                                                   
                    }                     
                });
                commMemberExpertiseFilter = inclusives.join(', ');
                $container.isotope();              
            }); 
            $('#distance-filter-community-member-list').on("change", function() {
                commMemberDistanceFilter = this.value;
                $container.isotope();            
            });

            $("#communityMemberListSearch").keyup(debounce(function(){                         
                commMemberKeywordSearchFilter = new RegExp( $("#communityMemberListSearch").val(), 'gi' );
                $container.isotope();
            } , 200));
```

Event though after appending I have called the isotope but it doesnt work.

```
$("#communitymembers").append(memberslist); 
$container.isotope();
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix with this,

```
$container.append(template).isotope('appended', template).isotope('layout');
```

That should works